# How do I load a native DLL in F# interactive?

Tags: f#, interop, f#-interactive

When trying to work with the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` nuget package, I get the following error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

This happens because one of the DLLs included with the package is a native DLL and cannot be referenced using the normal way to load a DLL in F# interactive (`#r "dllname.dll"`).

How can I load, or help F# interactive to find, the native DLL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that is necessary is to ensure that the FSI process is looking for DLLs in the directory that contains the native DLL. You don't need to reference it directly.

One way to accomplish this is to add it to the system path:

`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path",
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path") + ";" + __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"\..\packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient.15.112.1\lib\native\x86\")`

Some other options are explained at:

http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/loading-native-dlls-in-fsharp-interactive.html